# WordPress lightbox popup is working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php   
    class fppopupcontent {

        function __construct() {
            require_once('inc/init.php');

            if(isset($_POST['reset'])) {
                add_action('admin_init',array($this,'fppopupcontentreset'));
            }
        }

        function fppopupcontentadmin() {
            add_submenu_page('options-general.php','Fantastic Popup Content', 'Fantastic Popup Content', 'manage_options','fppopupcontentadmin', 'fppopupcontentadmin_menu');
        }

        function fppopupcontentupdate() {
            register_setting('fppopup','fppopupcontent');
            register_setting('fppopup','fppopuptitle');
            register_setting('fppopup','fppopupdays');
        }

        function fppopupcontentregister() {
            add_option('fppopupdays',0);    
        }

        function fppopupcontentreset() {
            delete_option('fppopuptitle');
            delete_option('fppopupcontent');
            delete_option('fppopupdays');
            add_option('fppopupdays','0');
            fppopupcontent::fppopupcontentmail();
        }

        function fppopupcontentprocess() {
            $plugin_dir = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);

            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
            wp_register_style('fp_style', $plugin_dir . 'css/home.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('fp_style');
            wp_register_script('fpquery_cookie', $plugin_dir . 'js/cookies.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('fpquery_cookie');
        }

        function fppopupcntnt() {
            if(is_home()) {
                ?>
                    <div id="fppop">
                        <div id="fp-close"></div>
                        <div id="fppopcnt">
                            <div id="fpclose" style="position:fixed;margin-left:-7px;"></div>
                            <div style="margin-left:50px">
                                <h1 style="font-size:24px"><?php echo get_option('fppopuptitle');?></h1>
                                <hr />
                                <?php $options=get_option('fppopupcontent'); ?>
                                <?php echo $options['textarea'] ; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php
            }
        }

        function fppopupprcss() {
            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document)
                        .ready(function($){
                            if($.cookie('popup_user_login')!='yes'){
                                $('#fppop')
                                    .delay(100)
                                    .fadeIn('medium');
                                $('#fpclose, #fp-close')
                                    .click(function(){
                                        $('#fppop')
                                            .stop()
                                            .fadeOut('medium')
                                    })
                            }
                            $.cookie(
                                'popup_user_login',
                                'yes',
                                {
                                    path:'/',
                                    expires:<?php echo (get_option('fppopupdays')); ?>
                                }
                            )
                        });
                </script>
            <?php
        }
    }


    add_filter('wp_footer',array('fppopupcontent','fppopupcntnt'));
    add_filter('wp_head', array('fppopupcontent','fppopupprcss'));
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',array('fppopupcontent','fppopupcontentprocess'));
    //add_action('wp_print_styles',array('fppopupcontent','fppopupcontentprocess'));
    add_action('admin_menu',array('fppopupcontent','fppopupcontentadmin'));
    add_action('admin_init',array('fppopupcontent','fppopupcontentupdate'));
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__,array('fppopupcontent','fppopupcontentregister'));
    $new = new fppopupcontent();
?>
```

I created a sample popup plugin.

In the above code it's working fine in the localhost.  But when I use this in the live site it is not working.

The code is appearing if I view using FireBug, but the CSS is set to `display:none`.

I tried changing the CSS to `display:block`, and then it displays but it will not close when I click the close button.

I don't know what I did wrong. If anyone can give me suggestions on how to do this, it would be great.

Following is the css that I used for the popup:

```
#fppop {
    display: block;
    background:color: #666;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}

#fp-close {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

#fppopcnt {
    background: white;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    left: 630px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 0 #939393;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 0 #CCC;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 0 #CCC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: -135px 0 0 -210px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#fpclose {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../images/fanclose.png) repeat;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-right: -22px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 **General**

Different PHP versions or environment settings may explain why you're getting different results.  eg the error below may be handled differently?

Check the PHP versions and WP versions of both your localhost and your live server.

---

2  **Your display problem**

I don't know if this is related, but you have the following errors in your code :

1. an extra `}` closing after your class closes (ie just prior to your `add_filter(...)` lines near the bottom
2. no opening `<?php` tag.

Although 2 and 3 may just be because there's code above this, that you've not included.

*EDIT: You've cleaned these errors up now by the looks.*

---

3  **Your close button**

*EDIT: Apologies, I overlooked your hard-coded script tags containing this code last time.*

The following code is associated to your close button(s):

```
jQuery(document)
    .ready(function($){
        if(jQuery(document)
.ready(function($){
    if($.cookies('popup_user_login')!='yes'){
        $('#fppop')
            .delay(100)
            .fadeIn('medium');
        $('#fpclose, #fp-close')
            .click(function(){
                $('#fppop')
                    .stop()
                    .fadeOut('medium')
            })
    }
    $.cookies(
        'popup_user_login',
        'yes',
        {
            path:'/',
            expires:<?php echo (get_option('fppopupdays')); ?>
        }
    )
});){
            $('#fppop')
                .delay(100)
                .fadeIn('medium');
            $('#fpclose, #fp-close')
                .click(function(){
                    $('#fppop')
                        .stop()
                        .fadeOut('medium')
                })
        }
        $.cookies(
            'popup_user_login',
            'yes',
            {
                path:'/',
                expires:<?php echo (get_option('fppopupdays')); ?>
            }
        )
    });
```

So it looks like you'll get no event bound on your `fpclose` and `fp-close` divs, unless `$.cookies('popup_user_login')!='yes'`.

You're including `cookies.js` in your WP `enqueue_script()` calls... but have you confirmed
a) this reference is being included in the emitted HTML?
b) that the `.cookies()` method is actually available at the point in your HTML you're calling it?
c) that the cookie you're referencing actually exists?

Comment: Thanks for your reply . My localhost version is PHP 5.4.3 But my live site version is PHP 5.2.17 what we do ?

Comment: @Vignesh 1. Can you please include a copy of the HTML source, as it appears in the browser when you browse to this page.  You're emmitting a combination of en-queued JScript, and hard-coded JScript (with some injected PHP values) so it's hard to tell what is actually available at the client.

Comment: @Vignesh 2. Have also updated my answer with re to your jQuery cookie code against the close buttons.